# Suggestion: Award reputation for badges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, badges

My proposal is to award reputation for earning badges. We all know SE depends on the community and it's contribution to be valuable and this contribution is also done by other tasks than asking questions, answering them and editing posts.
Apart from badges, there is currently no other way to be rewarded for other efforts that are also very valuable to the quality of the SE network, such as editing, flagging and commenting. I propose awarding amounts of reputation upon earning a badge. The amount can be higher for more difficult to earn badges.

On SO it is getting harder to contribute to questions and answers, because there are often multiple people attempting to answer the same question at the same time (this often results in people rushing to write an answer, in order not to be outposted by another user) and because the large audience asked most trivial questions already in the past.

Awarding reputation with badges allows active reviewers, editors and flaggers to increase their reputation with these actions, eventually giving them access to more area's of influence.

I recognize the risk people will hunt for badges more actively, decreasing quality, but I think this potentially negative effect will be smaller than the benefit of rewarding people for their efforts and the motivation gained if there is a reputational award.

Edit: Adding some new arguments:

1. Why is asking/answering stimulated more (by awarding both rep AND badges) than review/flag/comment (only badges)?
2. Being active reviewing/flagging/commenting should also eventually lead to unlocking privileges currently only unlocked by reputation.

**Basically: There are multiple ways to contribute, but half of these are not valued equally because no reputation is awarded / they offer no extra privileges.**

Comment: Badges are often given for things which already give reputation... I strongly suspect there's a high correlation between badges and rep already, and this would just reinforce it. (Really, do you want to give me more rep?)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Afraid of the competition? _*cough*_ Like we'll ever pass you _*cough*_ ;-)

Comment: Oh, and Jon is a perfect example of why we really don't need to add a rep reward to badges. There's plenty of rewards for other actions on SO.

Comment: You have less than 2000 reputation, so you gain two reputation points for an accepted suggested edit. This will operate up to a limit of 1000 points from edits. There are also questions with bounties. Otherwise, you have to avoid the easier questions so that there is more "room" to answer on more difficult ones :-) If you're answering in popular tags, you can expect more upvotes on your existing answers over time, if new viewers find them helpful (and know how to upvote).

Comment: Perhaps we should start awarding reputation for gaining reputation?

Comment: Since my arguments don't seem to be convincing enough ;), Here's one more: what's the motivation to keep reviewing/flagging/commenting? Besides 'helping others' and 'badges look cool' there aren't any. On the other hand: asking and editing contribute to these two _and_ earn reputation, offering a 3rd reason.

Comment: "what's the motivation to keep reviewing/flagging/commenting?" - to educate others and help keeping up the quality of the site?

Comment: @Oded can I have rep? I logged in the site today :)

Comment: @MeanGreen most actions taken on Stack by people are because people feel like they "owe" some kind of help back to a community that helped them :)

Comment: I agree to all stating helping should be the motivation, but then the questions is: Why is asking/answering stimulated more (by awarding both rep AND badges) than review/flag/comment (only badges)? And another point comes to mind: Shouldn't the privileges also be unlocked after x badges OR y reputation?

Comment: @MeanGreen Certain privileges are after certain badges, when it's appropriate to have them this way (Mjolnir comes to mind). Nothing is rewarded more than anything else... I'd say in fake internet points, they pretty much come down to the same. Also, if we give rep with badges... "good question", which already gives a TON of rep.. should give more?

Comment: @MeanGreen ["Robo-reviewers," who grind away at review queues just to get badges, are already a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits). We don't need more people reviewing just for the sake of getting reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [[Y]ou receive badges for being especially helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

The point of badges is to show that you've done *something* that is outside of the ask/edit/answer flow that is most common. Several of these badges are the *result* of reputation, showing that you are doing something right. The badge is a little pat on the back saying "Good Job! Keep doing what you are doing".

Adding reputation rewards for the badges doesn't provide the same "Look! I've done something right!" benefit. Someone may have a high reputation, but the little badges next to their name also show they've provided other benefits to the community. These may be [Great Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question) (a reputation based badge) or [Copy Editors](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor) (may or may not be reputation based, depending on when in your Stack Overflow career you edit) or [Marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal) (indirectly reputation based...you need the reputation to be able to flag) or [Publicists](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/262/publicist) (not reputation based).

The badges above, and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) are part of showing that you are involved in the community. They are your "[flair](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151804/quotes?item=qt1934650)".

Comment: ...DARN YOU ANDY. Now I need a way to get exactly 37 badges... I want 37 pieces of flair.

Comment: What is the good thing by the [tumbleweed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed) badge? "Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week."

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn Tumbleweed is a sort-of [consolation prize](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tumbleweed-badge).